# How to retrieve a windows user account password from administrator

Tags: windows-10

I have an `administrator` account and another account called `A`. I've forgotten the latter's password.

A typical way to get into the `A` is resetting its password from `administrator` by `net user A *`, but it's not what I need!

**I need to retrieve the current password of `A`, instead of resetting it** (simply because I have used this password for a couple of other things and I must recall that, as I can not reset those passwords as easy as my windows password!)

Is there any way to do that?!

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator: Thanks. I'll go for it.

Comment: No; there isn't an Administrator cannot retrieve a user profiles account

Comment: you could try http://www.openwall.com/john/ john the ripper it was not meant for win 10 but you could try it

Comment: here is a link with a tutorial https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-grab-crack-encrypted-windows-passwords-0146679/

Comment: Or try the free, open-source software Ophcrack http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Durfee: It can't make it.